# Using Buffered Reader to add user input to an array

Tags: java, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I use a buffered reader to read in the input and then it adds it to an array. But for some reason it only adds the last input to the array. I also want to check if the first input is zero... so thats what I am doing with the check variable. But the main problem is that it doesn't add it to the array.

```
public static void main (String[] Args) throws IOException
{
    int[] numbers = new int[100];

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader bReader;
    bReader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
    int intNumber = Integer.parseInt(bReader.readLine());
    int check = scan.nextInt();
    while (check != 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(bReader.readLine());
        check = intNumber;
        i++;
    }
    bReader.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move `int i = 0` outside of while loop. In each iteration `i` is getting initialized to 0 so your array is having only one value and that is in 0th index